# Using \lstinline[] changes all text colour in editor after use

Tags: listings

Ben using `\lstinline` today from the listings package... and every time I use it, it seems to change the colour of all text following it in texmaker to light brown... which is very annoying when trying to separate what is what in the text.

Anyone know why? and a fix?

This is how I'm using it...

```
price of the data set and finally a scalar float, \lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\small]$pct_change$, which defines the minimum percentage distance between each peak and trough.
```

Now literally all text following that last `$` is light brown...

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually guys don't worry... I skipped using it like that and used \ltset{} for the section instead... seems the [] in \lstinline were causing the issue no idea why.

Comment: got the same problem everytime i use `lstinline`. Doesn't matter if with or without options in brackets. Did you found out why that is?